# Why isnt my mongoDB update-function exited after successfully updating the document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to write a function that connects to my MongoDB and updates a specific document in a given collection. The updating itself works as expected. However, when I run the code, it doenst end after updating the document. Do you know why? Any help is very much appreciated.

```
function updateColletion(payload) {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true},
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Successfully connected');
    MongoDBModel.findByIdAndUpdate('exampleDocumentID', {
      payload
    }, 
    {upsert: true}, 
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("TrackerRegex updated.")
    });
  });
 };


const updatePayload = {exampleKey: exampleVar};
updateTrackerRegex(updatePayload);
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't end?

Comment: Good point. When i run the script with the update function (i. e. node updateHook.js) the process isn't exited. node doesnt move on the the next input line. (I hope thats clear)

Comment: Try disconnecting from the db.   Node won’t exit until all of the started processes have.

Comment: This usually happens when the promise is not fulfilled.

Comment: Wonderful. Indeed, closing the connection after the update did the trick. Thanks a lot everyone :)